# Definition of Analytic at point?

Tags: complex-analysis

A complex  function F is analytic at point $p$ if F is differentiable in some neighbourbood of $p$ (where neighbourbood take w.r.t usual metric on set of complex number). My question is if I have a function $F:D \to C$. (where D is the subset of complex number which contain only boundary of circle with radius 1, & origin as a Center). $F(z)=z$ (for all elements of $D$).Now is $F$ is analytic at $p=1+0 i $? (2) if it is then how can I find neighbourbood of it? (and it is interesting as no neighbourbood of $p$ contain  by domain).

Comment: For analyticity at $p$ the function has to be defined in some neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: @geetha290krm so nbhd of p are consider in entire complex plane or in domain(w.r.t restricted metric)?

Comment: In the entire complex plane.

Comment: @geetha290krm can we say if F is analytic on  domain D then D must be open set?

Comment: domains are taken to be open by definition, in the definitions I've seen

Comment: Being analytic “on $D$” does not require $D$ to be open, since you have already seen the case of $D$ being a point.  There are two steps: (1) define analyticity on open subsets, and then (2) define analyticity on a general subset $D$ to *mean* analyticity on an open set containing $D$. For example, being analytic on a closed half-plane ${\rm Re}(s) \geq 1$ means being analytic on an open set containing that closed half-plane.

Comment: @geetha290krm ignore this comment

Comment: @KCd what if our given function's domain is closed set? I mean how we assume the larger open set? Here i mean how can we extend function to it?as we only know images on given closed set

Comment: @MEETPATEL in an abstract situation you can’t specify exactly what the larger open set is. Can you give me a specific example (an analytic function on a closed set) that interests you?

Comment: @Kcd check my question ;i mentioned; it is analytic on my given domain? F(z)=z is obviously diffrentiable everywhere,but i am trying to check analyticity: and yes if we consider our domain as  a subspace then we have nbhd (as desired) but they are open in our domain ,not necessary open in entire C

Comment: @MEETPATEL a polynomial is analytic on the whole complex plane, so it is analytic on any (nonempty) subset.  It is a boring example. I was asking if you had an *interesting* example. The meaning of analytic on a subset is being analytic on a larger open subset of $\mathbf C$, not just an open subset of some subset of $\mathbf C$.

Answer (score 1):

When $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$, we say $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$ if $f$ is complex differentiable at every point of $\Omega$. If $C$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb C$, we say that $f$ is analytic on $C$ if $f$ is analytic on some open set containing $C$.

— from Stein & Shakarchi's book *Complex Analysis*.